# Get Category Level

Tags: mysql, sql, hierarchical-data

In MySql I have category table with fields:

- cat_id  (int)
- cat_parent_id (int)
- cat_name (string)

How to create query that return list off all categoryes with coresponded level number

cat parent_id for root nodes is 0

sample SQL Fiddle with sample data : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ba439ae/3

I have MySql version : 5.7.19 and Fiddle is on 5.6

Comment: See also many other questions with tag [tag:hierarchical-data].

Comment: @BillKarwin for me this is a totally different question. They looking for breadcrumbs I need result table with levels for some export... With knowledge of duplicated question, i maybe can create a solution for my case but it is not a duplicate.

Comment: I've reversed my vote for this to be a duplicate. But I suggest you to read a variety of the hierarchical-data questions. They may not be exactly the same as your query, but the principle is the same—query all descendants in a hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT 
    cat_id, 
    cat_parent_id,
    cat_name,
    0 AS level
  FROM category
  WHERE cat_parent_id = 0
  UNION ALL
  SELECT 
    cat.cat_id, 
    cat.cat_parent_id,
    cat.cat_name,
    (level + 1) AS level
  FROM category cat
  INNER JOIN cte c
    ON c.cat_id = cat.cat_parent_id
)

SELECT 
  cat_id, 
  cat_parent_id,
  cat_name,
  level
FROM cte
--ORDER BY level;
```

Comment: The OP said he is using MyQL 5.7. MySQL doesn't support CTE syntax until 8.0.

Comment: oooops.. Can use either a loop (while with cursor) ?

Comment: @StackOverflow thanks for this but this don't work in 5.7